# using std::bind2nd with thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

I'm trying to use std::bind2nd with thrust. I have code that compiles with a host pointer, but not with a device pointer. I think they are identical and should work in both cases.

```
// this compiles fine
thrust::host_vector<unsigned int> h_vec(nwords);
thrust::host_vector<unsigned int> h_map(nwords);
thrust::host_vector<unsigned int> h_out1(nwords);
thrust::copy_if(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), h_map.begin(), h_out1.begin(), 
                std::bind2nd(thrust::equal_to<int>(),1));

// this compilation fails with the error below
thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> d_map(nwords);
thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> d_vec(nwords);
thrust::device_vector<unsigned int> d_out1(nwords);
thrust::copy_if(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), d_map.begin(), d_out1.begin(), 
                std::bind2nd(thrust::equal_to<int>(),1));
```

When I try to call the second copy_if with the bind2nd I get the error below:

```
 /opt/cuda/include/thrust/detail/internal_functional.h(99): warning: calling a
 __host__ function from a __host__ __device__ function is not allowed
```

Is there another way to using adapters for binary functions in thrust? I have seen some people using "thrust::bind2nd" in examples on the web but I can't find that in any of our header files.

Comment: Use the placeholder expression `thrust::placeholders::_1 == 1` for this operation instead of trying to use something like `bind2nd`.

Comment: that is a good idea also. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to use adaptors in thrust. But if you want to use them on the GPU, the adaptor must be a __device__ function. This is why the first `copy_if` compiles and the second doesn't - your predicate is a host function, not a device function and the use of `device_vector` implies a device compilation trajectory.

In short, if you want an adaptor function for use on the GPU, you will need to write one yourself, the standard library ones (`bind1st`, `bind2nd`, `bind`) can't be used.

Comment: Thanks. Since I imagine standard stl doesn't have either __host__ or __device__ identifiers does it just default to __host__?

Comment: @SolArnu: Yes. Undecorated code (so no \_\_device\_\_ or \_\_host\_\_) defaults to the host compilation trajectory.