# Multiply device vector by constant

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, thrust

I am using thrust for a project, and it seem to be missing some basic functionality :-

In c++, the easiest way to multiply a vector by a constant is using `std::transform` and `std::bind1st` like so:

```
std::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(),
           std::bind1st(std::multiplies<double>(),myConst));
```

But apparently `bind1st` and `bind2nd` does not work with thrust.

So, is there an easy way to multiply a vector by a constant in thrust?

**PS**: Currently I am using my own functor to do the multiplication like so:

```
thrust::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), multiplyByConstant<double>(myConst))
```

where

```
    template< typename T >
    struct multiplyByConstant
    {
    const T constant;

    multiplyByConstant(T _constant) : constant(_constant) {}

     __host__ __device__
     void operator()( T& VecElem) const 
      {
        VecElem=VecElem*constant;
      }
    };
```

But writing a functor to do a simple multiplication seems like overkill. There surely must be an easier way.

Comment: Not being a cuda guy (and jealous of *all* of you for taking the time to envelope that kick-arse platform), are lamdas supported with that toolchain? (and sry if its a naive question, but it would seem a natural fit).

Comment: Thrust is an implementation __based on__ the Standard Template Library. It's not surprising it doesn't support everything. Please note that bind1st etc are deprecated and have been replaced by bind.

Answer (score 8):

Thrust can be made to work with adaptors, but `std::bind1st`, `std::bind2nd`, `std:bind` can't be used. You will need to write your own `__device__` adaptor function instead (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15160162/681865) for a little more information).

However, thrust 1.7 (should be available in CUDA 5.5 and newer) supports lambda expressions, so your example could be written as something like:

```
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>

using namespace thrust::placeholders;
thrust::transform(vec.begin(), vec.end(), vec.begin(), myConst * _1);
```

{disclaimer, written in browser, not tested, use at own risk}

If you are using an older CUDA release, then you are stuck with defining a functor.

Comment: Would this work also for complex arithmetics, when, for example, `vec` is a `thrust::device_vector<cuFloatComplex>` and `myConst` is the result of a `make_cuComplex`?

Comment: @JackOLantern - Not out of the box as cuFloatComplex doesn't define a * operator.  It's fairly easy however to define a binary_function that calls cuCmulf and then pass that into thrust::transform (or even a unary_function if multiplying a complex by a scalar).

Answer (score 5):

One simple way of accomplishing this is to use Thrust's fancy iterators, which often allow you to avoid defining (as many) functors. Instead of using std::bind1st to achieve a unary function from a binary function (and instead of using a lambda expression), you can use the binary function in conjunction with a fancy iterator:

```
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
...
thrust::transform(vec.begin(),
                  vec.end(), 
                  thrust::make_constant_iterator(myConst),
                  vec.begin(),
                  thrust::multiplies<int>());
```

The documentation for fancy iterators can be found [here](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__fancyiterator.html#ga0510c773bef5408b233245d5be5dab70).